# Memcpy within nested structures

Tags: c, structure, memcpy

I have two nested structures.

```
struct OS_CLASS {

  PAGE route_table[10];

}*sptr_vrf;

struct PAGE{
   int routes;
}


struct G-info{
   PAGE *displ_table;
} *global_info
```

I need to copy  sptr_vrf->route_table[0] to global_info->displ_table.

How can I do it using memcpy ?

Comment: Do you want deep or shallow copy?

Answer (score 0):

`memcpy(global_info->displ_table, &sptr_vrf->route_table[0], sizeof(struct PAGE));`